# Filter rows by groups where all values are NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I have difficulty removing rows in grouped data where all `value`s are `NA`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  File = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  value = c(1.111, 1.222, 1.121, 3.325, NA, 3.455, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

Filtering with `if_any` on the condition that **any** `value` is `NA` works as expected:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
#  group_by(File) %>%
  filter(!if_any(value, is.na))
  File value
1    A 1.111
2    A 1.222
3    A 1.121
4    B 3.325
5    B 3.455
```

But filtering with `if_all` on the condition that **all** `value`s of a group be `NA`does not work as expected - I get the same result as for `if_any`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(File) %>%
  filter(!if_all(value, is.na))
# A tibble: 5 × 2
# Groups:   File [2]
  File  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A      1.11
2 A      1.22
3 A      1.12
4 B      3.32
5 B      3.46
```

The expected result is:

```
1 A      1.11
2 A      1.22
3 A      1.12
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this what you are looking for:

```
df %>%
  group_by(File) %>%
  filter(all(!is.na(value)))
```

You group by `File` and only return groups rows where there are no `NA` values.
This matches your expected output.

But in your question you state that you only want to remove rows where **all** values are `NA`. You could achieve that with

```
df %>%
  group_by(File) %>%
  filter(any(!is.na(value)))
```

`if_any` and `if_all` are intended to use within `filer` when you want to filter across multiple columns. This is not what you want I guess.
Here is an example on how you would use `if_all`:

```
df2 <- tibble(
  x1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
  x2 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
)


df2 %>%
  filter(if_all(x1:x2, ~.)) #rows where x1 and x2 are TRUE

df2 %>%
  filter(if_any(x1:x2, ~.)) #rows where x1 or x2 are TRUE
```

### Update

If you have multiple columns then you can work with `if_all` or `if_any` depending on what it is you want:

```
df <- data.frame(   File = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),   val1 = c(1.111, 1.222, 1.121, 3.325, NA, 3.455, NA, NA, NA),   val2 = c(1.555, 1.666, 1.444, NA, NA, 3.455, NA, NA, NA) )



df %>%
  group_by(File) %>%
  filter(if_all(c(val1, val2), ~all(!is.na(.))))
```

Or similarly

```
  df %>%
      group_by(File) %>%
      filter(if_all(c(val1, val2), ~any(!is.na(.))))

  df %>%
      group_by(File) %>%
      filter(if_any(c(val1, val2), ~all(!is.na(.))))

  df %>%
      group_by(File) %>%
      filter(if_any(c(val1, val2), ~any(!is.na(.))))
```

Comment: But how do `if_any`and `if_all`work with grouped data where the aim is to remove all rows of a group if all or any values are NA, e.g., here: `df <- data.frame(
  File = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  val1 = c(1.111, 1.222, 1.121, 3.325, NA, 3.455, NA, NA, NA),
  val2 = c(1.555, 1.666, 1.444, NA, NA, 3.455, NA, NA, NA)
)`

Comment: Is this it: `df %>% group_by(File) %>% filter(!all(is.na(value)))`

Comment: This throws an error because there are the columns `val1`and `val2`

Comment: But actually the double `all` is a little too much and perhaps even confusing. In terms of logic I perfer this solution: `df %>%
  group_by(File) %>%
  filter(across(starts_with("v"), ~ !any(is.na(.))))`. But I've accepted the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

This was my approach :

```
my_df <- data.frame(
File = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
value = c(1.111, 1.222, 1.121, 3.325, NA, 3.455, NA, NA, NA)
)

my_df2 <- my_df %>% group_by(File) %>% filter(n() == sum(!is.na(value)))
```

Edit : My bad I thought you wanted only group where the value was equal to NA but it was the opposite so by adding the ! before the is.na will give you the expected result

Comment: The result is **incorrect**